# C++ - Initialize a pointer array of a certain size with all zeros

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following `C++` lines:

```
int len = 1000;
float *matrixAB = new float[len]();

//Stuff with matrixAB

delete [] matrixAB;
```

The array is declared ok, but I need all the values to be `0` and I can't figure out how to do this with a pointer array like this.

I'm sure this is super simple, but I can't find a reference. 
Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: They are all null, but I'd say use a vector instead.

Comment: when you have `()` in `float[len]()`, they are defaulted to 0

Comment: I need to use a `float *`. This array is being fed into `iOS's Accelerate.framework` and it only allows an array of type `float *`.

Comment: @billz Looks like you're right. I guess my problem is somewhere else. I'll update the post in a minute.

Comment: @Brett You can still use a `vector<float>` and access the underlying C-style array with the `data()` member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, use a `std::vector<float>`:

```c++
std::vector<float> matrixAB(len);
```

This will zero-initialize each element. And if you need to access a pointer to the array, use [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vector you can default initialize their value with:

```
vector<float> vMatrixAB(len ,0);//initialize len elements with the value 0
```

See this link as a ref: 
[std:vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

For a plain C array you can use memset

```
float matrixAB[len]={0};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your pointer array to zeros using `memset`. I've modified your code to demonstrate:

```
int len = 1000;
float *matrixAB = new float[len]();
memset(matrix, 0, len * sizeof(float));

//Stuff with matrixAB

delete [] matrixAB;
```